# Scipy.spatial.distance does not work when imported as normal

Tags: python, scipy, euclidean-distance

I am trying to calculate the euclidean distance between two points in my Python code. However, when I import scipy.spatial in the following way: `from scipy.spatial import distance` and when I call: `distance=distance.euclidean([5,2],[1,1])`, I get this error: `AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'euclidean'`. When I import scipy like this: `from scipy.spatial import distance as dist` and call `distance=dist.euclidean([5,2],[1,1])` it works. I don't understand how by renaming the import it actually works and when I don't rename it, it throws that error?

Comment: Welcome, I'd advise you post a minimal working example of the code in question in a nice and copy-paste friendly version. To format your code properly see this post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 1):

All works as expected, but you overwrite `distance` and errors are expected.

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
```

This is a normal import, and `distance` is a **module**. you can check this with

```
#distance is a module now
type(distance)
```

output:

```
module
```

Here you **overwrite** distance - this is bad style, and prone to errors.

```
distance=distance.euclidean([5,2],[1,1])
```

From here, `distance` is no longer a module, but overwritten to a `numpy.float64`. You can no longer do `distance.euclidean()` at this point. **If** you do, you get the error you showed, i.e.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-70ad947b0b7c> in <module>
      1 # .euclidean() is not defined for a numpy.float64
      2 # a error is expected
----> 3 distance=distance.euclidean([5,2],[1,1])

AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'euclidean'
```

---

Again, you can check indeed `distance` is a float with `type(distance)` which will return `numpy.float64`.

If you import with a different name as:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist

distance=dist.euclidean([5,2],[1,1])
```

Nothing is overwritten. So all is good and we are fine and stay fine.

Or use

```
my_distance=distance.euclidean([5,2],[1,1])
```

- Don't mixup modules names with variables.
- Don't overwrite to different types in general to avoid confusion/errors.

Comment: You could add an explicit comment about the strong recommendation to use a different variable name.  E.g. `my_distance = distance.euclidean([5,2],[1,1])`

Answer (score 0):

For me this code runs without trouble:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
a=distance.euclidean([5,2],[1,1])
print(a)

from scipy.spatial import distance as dist
b=dist.euclidean([5,2],[1,1])
print(b)
```

Output:

```
4.123105625617661
4.123105625617661
```

My scipy is version 1.4.1